# Forms that are technically the same size have different sizes at runtime

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, properties, size

I've been getting this problem with a C# application. The main form (the one in Application.Run()) has its size set to 1300, 800, and I edited all the other forms' size property to be the same. However, at runtime, the main form is considerably bigger than the others. 
Does anyone know what might cause this/how it can be fixed? 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have autosize turned off? Also if you want help that is more than us making guesses, please post your code.

Comment: Can you include the code you are trying to run? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Jacobr365 Yes, what does that mean? Either way, problem was solved by changing the font and font size of all forms to be the same.

Comment: Thank you both for answering, btw :) I didn't see the point in including the code, since I hadn't made any size-related changes in the code editor and only used the Properties window for that.

Comment: Auto size is a form property that controls if the form auto resizes for changes in fonts or whatever ever. If it is turned on your boxes will change size on you. I am pretty sure by default it is on.